# how can i use fileinput to edit multiple files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am using os.walk in python 2.7 to open multiple files, then, add all lines of interest of those files to a list. Later I'd want to edit those lines with fileinput and close it. How can I achieve this? Using the code below is how I'm opening the files:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import fileinput

lines = []

def openFiles():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/test1/'):
        for lists in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.txt"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, lists)
            print filepath
            with open(filepath, "r") as sources:#opens 8 files and read their lines
                #edit = fileinput.input(filepath, inplace=1)
                for line in sources:
                    if line.startswith('xe') :
                      lines.append(line)
```

Then later, for each lines that start with xe, I'd like to add a # in front of it then close that file. I'd like to do that in a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way. But I'm using classes in my main code so It's split into 2 functions instead of one. In my main code, I used a list to hold all the file paths and use fileinput to open each filepaths from the list this way  `for line in fileinput.FileInput(pathlist, inplace=1): do something.` I do thank @direprobs for her answer, as she shed some light on how I'm supposed to do this.

```
import fnmatch
import fileinput
import os
import sys

def openFiles():
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/test1/'):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.txt"):
            filepaths = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            for line in fileinput.FileInput(filepaths, inplace=1):
                if line.startswith("xe"):
                    add = "# {}".format(line)
                    line = line.replace(line, add)
                sys.stdout.write(line)
                fileinput.close()


openFiles()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the I way I do it, adding to your code:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import fileinput


def openFiles(dir):
    filePaths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for textFile in fnmatch.filter(files, "*.txt"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, textFile)
            filePaths.append(filepath)
    return filePaths  

def prefixLines(filepaths, chartoPrefix, prefixWith):
    res = '' 
    for filepath in filepaths: 
        # Read file
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
           for line in f: 
                if line.startswith(chartoPrefix):
                    res += prefixWith + line 
                else: 
                    res += line 
        # Write to file
        with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
            f.write(res)
        res = ''                                  # Rest res                                                  

prefixLines(openFiles(r'/home/test1/'), 'xe', '#')
```

`prefixLines` suffers from many shortcomings:

- Because we read all the lines of files and store them in `res`, we
  may ran out of memory for large files.
- If somehow the programmer forgot to indent `res = ''` in the
  right block or if `res` was completely omitted and the code ran on
  actual files that the user needs, you'll end up writing the contents
  of the previous read file to the next file and the last
  file will have the contents of *all* the read files. That's why you
  have use this code in a testing environment or use it cautiously.

This code only serves to demonstrate how you could achieve your desired effects, prefixing file lines that starts with a string with another string. Therefore, a slight improvement of this code is recommended. For example, instead of reading all the contents of the file and storing them at `res` you could simply save the line number that needs to be prefixed and thus eliminating the need to load all the data into memory. `enumerate` could also be helpful to return the file number, it returns an iterable in 2.7. By obviating `res` not only do we save memory, but also eliminate the shortcoming in bullet 2.

Comment: Thanks, you've help me in finding a way to do this