# Creating a .txt file of file directories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a .txt file of file directories at a location, remove the prefixes and save the text file.

I use the `os.walk` module to build a list of directories of a location into a .txt file. I always get the text file of the directories.

The part where it removes the prefixes of those lines of directories in the next chunk of code doesn't work. It creates its own .txt file (as it is supposed to) but it is always empty.

If there is a solution that does all of this in one .txt file and one block of code that would be even better!

Here is what I have so far, and I'm using dummy directories for privacy's sake.

```
 import os
    from datetime import datetime

    # this is to create a filename with the timestamp_directory_list for a .txt file
    now = datetime.now()
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_directory_list.txt")


    # uses os module to walk the directories and files 
# within a given location, then writes it line by line to a .txt file
    with open(filename, "w") as directory_list:
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r"C:/Users"):
            for filenameX in files:
                f = os.path.join(path)
                directory_list.write(str(f) + os.linesep)


    # Open up .txt file, read a line, trim the prefix, then save it
    # this is to create a filename with the timestamp_directory_list for a .txt file
    trim = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_trimmed_directories.txt")

    def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
        # Remove prefix from supplied text string
        if prefix in text:
            return text[len(prefix):]
        return text

    with open(filename, "r") as trim_input, \
        open(trim, "a") as trim_output:

        for line in trim_input:
            print line
            if "C" in line:
                print line
                trim_output = remove_prefix(trim_input, 'C')
                trim_output.write(line+ os.linesep)
```

Comment: There's a similar question to yours here: [how can i use fileinput to edit multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655566/how-can-i-use-fileinput-to-edit-multiple-files/43657282#43657282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've mixed up the variable names, actually I'd expect that if run it would raise some exceptions.

- you have `trim_output` for both the output file and the trimmed line
- you are calling `remove_prefix` on the "input_file_object" not on the `line`
- you get the trimmed line (overriding, I think, the output file refference), but you write the (not trimmed) line to the output file

your code should be something like

```
with open(filename, "r") as trim_input, \
        open(trim, "a") as trim_output:
    for line in trim_input:
        print line
        if "C" in line: 
            # this if is a bit useless you have an another if inside the remove_prefix, 
            # also you are skyping all the lines without prefix
            print line
            trimmed_line = remove_prefix(line, 'C')
            trim_output.write(trimmed_line+ os.linesep)
```

**Later edit:**
in order to have the code behave as stated in the initial description the "if" should not be present, and the code unindented by one level

also the `remove_prefix` is flawed

```
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    # Remove prefix from supplied text string
    if prefix in text: 
        # if prefix is "C", this is true for "Ctest" and also for "testC"
        return text[len(prefix):] # but it removes the first chars
    return text
```

it should be

```
def remove_prefix(text, prefix):
    # Remove prefix from supplied text string
    if text and text.startswith(prefix): 
        return text[len(prefix):]
    return text
```

Comment: thank you! So then is this the best way to go about this section? Or would moving the actual prefix to the def remove_prefix block be a cleaner way to do this without skipping the lines without the prefix?

Comment: in my answer I've just "corrected" your code, keeping the present "logic". looking at the description of what it should do ... yes, the if should not be present in this section, because if present, in the output file you would get only the lines that have the prefix